# What happen to my bitcoin

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, trading, transaction-verification

I have payed last april 21 and april 25 should be my payment but it took days already here is my transaction id

b5a9cb6a67429ec60c51f3aa197bec67af0003c841890132051f9fea40f71f76

And the same as april 22 and i should get my bitcoin on april 26 transaction id

77fc2aa152a80e0abe382a53d5254f113460a6f17cff95852bd0827a572e01cb

I waited how many days just for bitcoin to go to my wallet but it say bitcoin network i dont why and what happen ?please i need help

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction are NOT unconfirmed. As you can see here:
https://blockchain.info/tx/b5a9cb6a67429ec60c51f3aa197bec67af0003c841890132051f9fea40f71f76
https://blockchain.info/tx/77fc2aa152a80e0abe382a53d5254f113460a6f17cff95852bd0827a572e01cb

Both of them have over 700 confirmations. All, but one of your outputs are already spent.